# Configuring Sesame with Allegrograph

Tags: sesame, allegrograph

How can I configure Sesame with Allegrograph? I know agraph provides similar API's ti Sesame's ones. However, I'd like to use Alibaba.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Allegrograph provides a fully compatible implementation of the [Sesame Repository API](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/api/index.html?org/openrdf/repository/package-summary.html). To combine this with Alibaba, just create a new [AGRepository](http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/3.2/agraph-javadoc/index.html?com/franz/ag/repository/package-summary.html) object, and provide it to Alibaba's [ObjectRepositoryFactory](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/alibaba/2.0-beta12/apidocs/index.html?org/openrdf/repository/object/config/ObjectRepositoryFactory.html):

```
Repository agRep = new AGRepository(...);
ObjectRepository alibaba = ObjectRepositoryFactory.createRepository(agRep);
```

See Franz Inc.'s own [tutorial materia](http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/learning/Tuple-Queries.lhtml)l for details on how to create Repository objects that connect to an Allegrograph server.